# grep -P recursion match whole line

Tags: regex, grep, pcre

I'm trying to write a grep -P command that output the lines in test.txt containing only the characters A and B such that there are exactly n A's followed by exactly n B's and no other characters.  e.g. AABB AAABBB AB AAAABBBB

test.txt is a file with a bunch of patterns, one in each line.

I've come across the page https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html?wlr=1 which tells

```
grep -P 'A(?R)?B' test.txt
```

will work. And indeed this pattern works when testing in Regex101.

However when I test out the command on terminal, apparently this command also matches the lines that contains this pattern, e.g. ABABAB ABBAAABBBB

Given that, I try the following instead but it doesn't work like how regex do.

```
grep -P '^A(?R)?B$' test.txt
```

So my question is how to make grep -P matches the whole line? I found something about modifier on the man page but it doesn't lead me to anywhere so far.

Answer (score 3):

You can use anchors and recurse the first subpattern using a [subroutine](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#subroutines) `(?1)`.

Using `(?R)` recurses the [entire pattern](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html).

```
grep -P '^(A(?1)*B)$' test.txt
```

Comment: you can also use `-x` option for matching entire line in `grep`

Comment: @Sundeep I could not actually get the `grep -Px 'A(?R)?B'` work with `-x`. See [demo](https://ideone.com/UC683M).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah, that didn't work for me too.. `grep -xP '(A(?1)?B)'` works